Combine and adjust overlapping date ranges without using a loop?
Here's an example. Here a have a table with 3 columns. I want to combine records that have overlapping dates. Let's call record 1 our primary record because it has the lowest FromDate. So looking at this table, record 2's FromDate is within record 1's From-End Date range. Now what I want to do is add the number of days in record 2's date range to my primary's EndDate, making it now 2024-01-11. And then moving on to check record 3's FromDate against our Primary's FromDate and EndDate (which we just changed from 2024-01-06 to 2024-01-11). And yes it falls in that range, so again I add the number of days in record 3's range to my primary's EndDate, changing it from 2024-01-11 to 2024-01-16. Record 4 doesn't apply because it's FromDate is not within the primary's date range so I want to leave it as is. Is there a way I can achieve this without the use of a loop?



Id
FromDate
EndDate




1
2024-01-01
2024-01-06


1
2024-01-05
2024-01-10


1
2024-01-08
2024-01-13


1
2024-02-05
2024-02-10



I am currently still brainstorming ideas. All I have is chicken scratch.

with dataX as (select *, case when lag(EndDate) > FromDate then 1 end) over (partition by id order by FromDate) as brk from T), groups as (select *, count(brk) over (partition by id order by FromDate) as grp from dataX) select id, min(FromDate), max(End date), grp from groups group by id, grp; Key is basically looking back to find the rows that don't overlap and then numbering them.

There's an answer section. @shawnt00 .

Yeah, I'm tired of all the drama that goes along with writing answers and I really don't want rep for all the repeat questions anyway.

This appears to be more than a typical gaps-and-islands problem because of the cumulative adjustments applied to end-date as long as each new date-range is within reach of the prior adjusted range. LAG() can no longer be used to test for gaps. A row can be grouped with rows back to some group start date IF the difference between the group start date and the row start date is <= the sum of prior rows' duration in that group AND every row in between satisfies that condition. My gut feeling is that this cannot be done without a look or a recursive CTE that simulates a loop.

A couple of questions: (1) Is EndDate an exclusive end date, such that the first two rows in your sample data only overlap by one day and the second row EndDate is only adjusted upwards by one day? This seems to be the case. (2) If you had another row with a start date of 2024-01-16, would that be included in the same group as your first three rows because of the adjusted EndDates? I would expect "yes". (3) Are you looking to just calculate the combined ranges, or do you need to modify the initial data with a combination of updates and deletes?

@shawnt00 I'm all about SO needing more friendliness, but four lines of pure code in comments is just too far

If it's a repeat, there's also a close as duplicate feature. Answering questions (in the comments) that are duplicates only promotes asking of duplicate questions, @shawnt00 .

Funny thing @ThomA is that a supposed dup question was pretty much the final straw for me on here. I had a very clean solution and an accepted answer when another higher-rep dude comes along and fully misunderstands what was going on, complaining it's wrong, that somebody will inappropriately use the answer, and then closes it as a dup despite all my explaining so he can point to his old answer.

It was about birthdays being stored as dates (all stored with the same year of 2020.) I briefly pointed out some of the considerations surrounding the observation of leap day birthdays in non-leap years. And some applications, say legal age for alcohol purchase, should treat the anniversary as March 1 even though people might celebrate on Feb 28. In short, my answer was probably superior and even the most experienced users suck at marking dups and this is one of the biggest complaints from people with bad experiences on SO.

This is a variation of the gaps and islands problem, where the solution is to identify gaps in the date ranges, and then group the data into islands between the gaps that are then merged to form the final result.
The problem is that the definition of a gap is not as simple as a comparison between the start-date of the current row and the end-date or the prior row. This is because the prior end-date for the group may be adjusted due to overlaps among other date-ranges within the group.
Because of this, I believe the solution requires a recursive CTE (common table expression) that simulates a loop and builds cumulative date-ranges while checking for adjacency or overlap with later candidate rows.
The following first assigns sequence numbers to each row and uses a recursive CTE to build the combined date ranges, with logic to reset whenever a gap is detected.
WITH NumberedData AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY StartDate) AS RowNum
    FROM Data
),
CombinedData AS ( -- Recursive CTE
    SELECT
        ND.*,
        1 AS GroupNum,
        ND.StartDate AS CombinedStartDate,
        ND.EndDate  AS CombinedEndDate
    FROM NumberedData ND
    WHERE ND.RowNum = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        ND.*,
        CD.GroupNum + CALC.IsGap AS GroupNum,
        CASE WHEN CALC.IsGap = 0
            THEN CD.CombinedStartDate -- Continue
            ELSE ND.StartDate         -- Reset
            END AS CombinedStartDate,
        CASE WHEN CALC.IsGap = 0
            THEN DATEADD(day, CALC.CurrentDuration, CD.CombinedEndDate) -- Extend
            ELSE ND.EndDate          -- Reset
            END AS CombinedEndDate
    FROM CombinedData CD
    JOIN NumberedData ND
        ON ND.Id = CD.Id
        AND ND.RowNum = CD.RowNum + 1
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN ND.StartDate > CD.CombinedEndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsGap,
            DATEDIFF(day, ND.StartDate, ND.EndDate) AS CurrentDuration
    ) CALC
)
-- SELECT CD.* FROM CombinedData CD ORDER BY CD.Id, CD.RowNum
SELECT
    CD.Id,
    CD.GroupNum,
    COUNT(*) AS CombinedRows,
    MIN(CD.CombinedStartDate) AS CombinedStartDate,
    MAX(CD.CombinedEndDate) AS CombinedEndDate
FROM CombinedData CD
GROUP BY CD.Id, CD.GroupNum
ORDER BY CD.Id, CD.GroupNum

Results:



Id
GroupNum
CombinedRows
CombinedStartDate
CombinedEndDate




1
1
3
2024-01-01
2024-01-16


1
2
1
2024-02-05
2024-02-10



See this db<>fiddle for a demo with some extra test data.
The above assumes that EndDate is an exclusive end-date (which actually works nicely when working with date or date ranges. If you need to use inclusive end-dates, I would suggest calculating DATEADD(day, 1, EndDate) AS EndDateExclusive in the first CTE, perform all intermediate calculations using that EndDateExclusive value, and finally adjust that end-date (subtract a day) in your final result.
If you only wish to combine overlapping date ranges (after adjustments), but not adjacent date ranges, you can change the > to >= in the IsGap calculation.

If you need to accumulate and redistribute the overlaps then you need a loop or recursion (which is still basically a loop). There's no way to determine the start of a reset/anchor without going through all the rows before it. Here's an option that doesn't require a cursor or dealing with a lot of variables. Instead it does in-place updates until there are no more overlaps. You might find this especially suitable for temp tables:
declare @r int = 1;
while @r > 0 begin
    with laggedT as (
        select *,
            lag(EndDate) over (partition by Id
                               order by FromDate, EndDate) as laggedEndDate
        from T
    )
    update laggedT
    set FromDate = dateadd(day, 1, laggedEndDate),
         EndDate = dateadd(day, datediff(day, FromDate, laggedEndDate) + 1, EndDate)
    where laggedEndDate >= FromDate;
    set @r = @@rowcount;
end

https://dbfiddle.uk/Q88viY5-
It wasn't clear exactly how the definition of overlap should work but the date comparison and days adjustment should be trivial to modify as necessary.
For the recursive approach, this one should minimize the number of iterations (recursion depth). This query works even where date ranges are duplicated:
with dataX as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by Id order by FromDate, EndDate) as rn,
        datediff(day, FromDate, EndDate) + 1 as currentDays,
        datediff(day,
            -- order by is redundant on min here but the query plan
            -- will reuse the same sort as the other analytic functions
            min(FromDate) over (partition by Id order by FromDate, EndDate),
            FromDate) as offsetDay,
        sum(datediff(day, FromDate, EndDate) + 1)
            over (partition by Id
                  order by FromDate, EndDate
                  rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as totalDays
    from T
), r as (
    select Id, rn, totalDays, FromDate, EndDate from dataX
    where offsetDay = 0 and totalDays - currentDays = 0 or offsetDay > totalDays
    union all
    select t.Id, t.rn, t.totalDays,
        dateadd(day, r.totalDays - t.offsetDay, t.FromDate),
        dateadd(day, r.totalDays - t.offsetDay, t.EndDate)
    from r inner join dataX as t
        on t.Id = r.Id and t.rn = r.rn + 1 and t.offsetDay <= r.totalDays
)
select Id, FromDate, EndDate from r order by Id, FromDate, EndDate;

https://dbfiddle.uk/ylYeunQY
